# php regex to extract multiple matches from string

Tags: php, regex, file

I'm trying to make a php regex to extract multiple sections/conditions from one string... let me show you what I'm talking about; this is an excerpt from the total file contents (the real contents contain hundreds of these groupings):

```
part "C28"
{ type       : "1AB010050093",
  %cadtype   : "1AB010050094",
  shapeid    : "2_1206",
  descr      : "4700.0000 pFarad 10.00 % 100.0 - VE5-VS3",
  insclass   : "CP6A,CP6B",
  gentype    : "RECT_032_016_006",
  machine    : "SMT",
  %package   : "080450E",
  %_item_number: "508",
  %_Term_Seq : "" }
part "C29"
{ type       : "1AB008140029",
  shapeid    : "2_1206",
  descr      : "150.0000 pFarad 5.00 % 100.0 Volt NP0 CERAMIC CAPACITOR",
  insclass   : "CP6A,CP6B",
  gentype    : "RECT_032_016_006",
  machine    : "SMT",
  %package   : "080450E",
  %_item_number: "3",
  %_Term_Seq : "" }
```

As you can see, the data in the excerpt repeats twice.  I need to search through the whole file and extract the following:

- string after the word "part" -- which would be "C28" or "C29"
- string after the "type" property -- which would be "1AB010050093" or "1AB008140029"

So, essentially, I need to get all the part references and associated types out of this file...and I'm not sure the best way to go about doing this.

Please let me know if more info is needed to help... thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a Json parser for this data type?

Comment: @Denomales While it looks similar, the example is not JSON data, and would not work with PHP's `json_decode`.

Comment: Fair enough. I had to ask.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Description

This expression will:

- capture the group name as `ref`
- capture the values of the `type` and `descr` fields.
- The Type field when captured should be put into a named group called `partnumber`
- The fields can appear in any order in the body
- the `descr` field is optional and should only be captured if it exists. The `(?:`...``` )?`` brackets around the ```descr` field makes the field optional

Note this is a single expression so you'll in to use the `x` option to so the regex engine ignore white space.

```
^part\s"(?P<ref>[^"]*)"[^{]*{
(?:(?=[^}]*\sdescr\s*:\s+"(?P<descr>[^"]*)"))?
(?=[^}]*\stype\s*:\s+"(?P<type>[^"]*)")
```

[image]

## PHP Code Example:

**Input Text**

```
part "C28"
{ type       : "1AB010050093",
  %cadtype   : "1AB010050094",
  shapeid    : "2_1206",
  descr      : "4700.0000 pFarad 10.00 % 100.0 - VE5-VS3",
  insclass   : "CP6A,CP6B",
  gentype    : "RECT_032_016_006",
  machine    : "SMT",
  %package   : "080450E",
  %_item_number: "508",
  %_Term_Seq : "" }
part "C29"
{ type       : "1AB008140029",
  shapeid    : "2_1206",
  descr      : "150.0000 pFarad 5.00 % 100.0 Volt NP0 CERAMIC CAPACITOR",
  insclass   : "CP6A,CP6B",
  gentype    : "RECT_032_016_006",
  machine    : "SMT",
  %package   : "080450E",
  %_item_number: "3",
  %_Term_Seq : "" }
part "C30"
{ type       : "1AB0081400 30",
  shapeid    : "2_1206 30",
  insclass   : "CP6A,CP6B 30",
  gentype    : "RECT_032_016_006 30",
  machine    : "SMT 30",
  %package   : "080450E 30 ",
  %_item_number: "3 30 ",
  %_Term_Seq : "30" }
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/^part\s"(?P<ref>[^"]*)"[^{]*{
(?:(?=[^}]*\sdescr\s*:\s+"(?P<descr>[^"]*)"))?
(?=[^}]*\stype\s*:\s+"(?P<partnumber>[^"]*)")/imsx',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Matches**

```
$matches Array:
(
[ref] => Array
    (
        [0] => C28
        [1] => C29
        [2] => C30
    )

 [descr] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4700.0000 pFarad 10.00 % 100.0 - VE5-VS3
        [1] => 150.0000 pFarad 5.00 % 100.0 Volt NP0 CERAMIC CAPACITOR
        [2] => 
    )

[partnumber] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1AB010050093
        [1] => 1AB008140029
        [2] => 1AB0081400 30
    )

)
```

Comment: @Denomales where do you get the regex visualization image from?

Comment: @tristanbailey, I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds, named capture groups, or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Comment: @Denomales, great solution, I know I didn't talk about this in my OP but how would I get the matched results from elements [1] and [2] together?  For instance, one element from the final result should look like: `[0] => Array( ['ref'] => C28, ['partnumber'] => 1AB010050093 )` Notice that I've kept the relation C28 goes with 1AB010050093, and so on...

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to capture part number as a named capture, and how to capture additional fields in the same run. I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Denomales that is indeed a cool way to do it, I opened another question in the meantime to get some resolution and this is what I was actually looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256923/php-merge-2-arrays-into-one-associative-array thanks for the unique insight though

Comment: @Denomales, I'm actually having issues with the real implementation of this.  `$matches` is not returning anything for me.  The file where I'm getting all my input text is actually 3MB (not sure if that is over the memory size limit, so I put an `ini_set("memory_limit","10M");` at the beginning of the code.  `$matches` returns an array with 3 empty elements... What could be going on?

Comment: @Denomales, so, could it be my file size? Maybe it is too large for the memory buffer or something... I've echoed my input text before attempting the regex match and the whole file contents is actually inside my variable...

Comment: Here is the same script, with a little more of my original file contents added to the input string, and for some reason it doesn't work... could you pin-point this? http://3v4l.org/qIAZM

Comment: it doesn't work because the sample code differs slightly from the sample you provided. Specifically this regex expects the string `part` to appear at the start of the line, whereas in the sample link, the string appears after some white space. To correct for this just insert the `\s*` right after the `^` and it should work for you too. http://3v4l.org/8cuFb

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each groups have the same structure, you can use this pattern:

```
preg_match_all('~([^"]++)"[^{"]++[^"]++"([^"]++)~', $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

EDIT:

Notice: if you have more informations to extract, you can easily transform your datas into json, example:

```
$data = <<<LOD
part "C28"
{ type       : "1AB010050093",
  %cadtype   : "1AB010050094",
  shapeid    : "2_1206",
  descr      : "4700.0000 pFarad 10.00 % 100.0 - VE5-VS3",
  insclass   : "CP6A,CP6B",
  gentype    : "RECT_032_016_006",
  machine    : "SMT",
  %package   : "080450E",
  %_item_number: "508",
  %_Term_Seq : "" }
part "C29"
{ type       : "1AB008140029",
  shapeid    : "2_1206",
  descr      : "150.0000 pFarad 5.00 % 100.0 Volt NP0 CERAMIC CAPACITOR",
  insclass   : "CP6A,CP6B",
  gentype    : "RECT_032_016_006",
  machine    : "SMT",
  %package   : "080450E",
  %_item_number: "3",
  %_Term_Seq : "" }
LOD;
$trans = array( "}\n"   => '}, ' , 'part'  => ''    ,
                "\"\n{" => ':{"' , ':'     => '":'  ,
                "\",\n" => '","' );

$data = str_replace(array_keys($trans), $trans, $data);
$data = preg_replace('~\s*+"\s*+~', '"', $data);
$json_data =json_decode('{"'.substr($data,1).'}');

foreach ($json_data as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<br/><br/>part: ' . $key . '<br/>type: ' . $value->type;    
}
```